# prometheus query to determine REDIS CPU utilization

Tags: redis, prometheus

I'm having to find and display in grafana the CPU utilization of REDIS nodes which have prometheus exporter installed in them. I imported the grafana dashboard available here -https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/2751 . It has a panel for memory utilization, but does not have a panel for CPU utilization. I searched in the internet for a prometheus query for finding the CPU utilization, but I have not had a luck so far. Any references for such a query would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The dashboard you mentioned assumes you're using the [redis_exporter](https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter) to collect metrics about your redis instance.

To show CPU usage, you can add a panel with this query:

`rate(redis_cpu_user_seconds_total{addr="$addr"}[1m])`

(check your metrics labels, you might need to use `instance` instead of `addr` in the above query but that depends on your Prometheus setup).